# How to bill shipping charges on customer FedEx or UPS account in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, customer-account, fedex, ups

I want to add functionality that customer can pay their shipping charges on their FedEx or ups account like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use following extension https://marketplace.magento.com/magemaclean-m2-myshipping.html